Question About My Border Collie’s Play Behavior
My dog is a 6-year-old spayed female Border Collie. When she plays with other dogs, she tends to grab their neck fur and makes a soft growling sound, but she doesn’t actually bite them. This behavior bothers me a bit because I’m worried other dog owners might take it the wrong way. Additionally, when other dogs run off, she lies down and waits for them to come back and continue playing, which reminds me of how she used to behave when I took her herding. Could you help me understand why she behaves this way? Thank you!

It sounds like your Border Collie is herding more than playing (or they're mixing the two behaviours together). This can be fine for some dogs and as a type of play but more often, dogs don't appreciate a lot of the behaviours that come with herding (being stalked, being started at, soft growling, neck grabbing, small nips, etc.). That could get ugly fast depending on how the other dog reacts — which you can't control.
You'll need to be mindful and watch the behaviour/reactions of the dogs your Border Collie is playing with in this manner and if they're open to playing back or showing signs of displacement, anxiousness, etc. This isn't limited to you and your herding dog but hopefully gets applied to all dogs and owners. The way dogs play will vary greatly between different dogs and the more owners that are able to identify warning signs and signals that a dog is potentially uncomfortable, the sooner they can intervene and avoid a bad situation. Consider getting to know other dogs and their owners and only letting your Border Collie play this way if it's accepted by the other dog.
You may want to consider discourage your Border Collie from herding behaviours with other dogs. Or at least having the ability to stop your dog from continuing when needed. To discouraging when you see this happen, you can try distracting your dog with a command, recalling your dog and then reward for doing so. Aiming to first break the focus, second reinforce that coming to you is good and third, reinforcing that they shouldn’t be doing that.
Disclaimer for the last paragraph: I referenced an answer from a reddit thread here that shared my views.
